# How can I get highchart graphs to display in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, htmlwidgets

I am creating an html document and want to include interactive visualizations. When I use highcharter in RStudio, my graph displays perfectly, but when I put the same code in RMarkdown, I keep getting errors: "could not find function 'hchart'; could not find function 'hcaes'".

I have been using this page as a guide, but I can't get my graphs to display:
https://www.kaggle.com/nulldata/beginners-guide-to-highchart-visual-in-r/code

This is the code I've tried using:

```
highcharter::hchart(TEST,
         type = "column",
         hcaes(x = `Service.Month`,
               y = value,
               group = variable)) %>%
    hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
    hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Service Month")) %>%
    hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Total Number")) %>%
    hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE,
               backgroundColor = "#FCFFC5",
               shared = TRUE) %>%
    hc_title(text = "Title")
```

Comment: What happens when you set `library(highcharter)` in front of it?

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thanks so much!